# Ionic, Crosswalk, TalkBack, and Accessibility (A11Y)

Tags: ionic-framework, accessibility, talkback

I am currently building a hybrid app using Ionic Framework.  This app must support accessibility.  In iOS, VoiceOver works great!  But in TalkBack on Android, overall it works decent but having a few issues so I decided to try Crosswalk.  In Crosswalk, Talkback seems to be working better.  BUT, if the app pauses then resumes, elements are no longer high-lighted even though TalkBack is still on.  Do you have any ideas how to resolve this?  Does anyone else have this problem?

Thanks,

Chris